# Sorting Not Working in the Search Results Web Part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search-results, people-search, sorting

I noticed that the Web Part itself has a “Show Sort Dropdown” option. This is turned off by default but I’ve just noticed that that it is still functioning behind the scenes. Hence the default JSON configuration is to sort by. Here Trying To Sort PreferredName By Alphabetical Order but Not working
 Here is the JSON I used :

[{"name":"A-Z","sorts":[{"p":"PreferredName","d":0}]},{"name":"Z-A","sorts":[{"p":"PreferredName","d":1}]}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please confirm, that PreferredName is enabled for sorting in the Search Service Application!

SSA > Search Schema > Managed Properties > Search for "PreferredName" > Sorting Enabled

Answer (score 0):

In the search results webpart you need to enable the "show sort dropdown" for this to work (setting the JSON sort order).

If this is not ticked, the webpart will not listen to the sort order you specify in the JSON.

You can though, hide the sort dropdown with some css if you need to sort on another property, but do not want to enable your users to change the sort order.

Depending on your requirements the Content by Search webpart might suite you better

Comment: Hello Robert Sir, Currently in My search results webpart "show sort dropdown"  is Enable,Still it Not Display Result