# SharePoint 2013 REST search API sort result by refiners

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, rest, search-results, refiner

Is possible to sort (order by) a REST search result by RefinementName? Thank you

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refiners='Wiki'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your search query with **sortlist** for sort or orderby your results in search + REST API

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='searchtext'&sortlist='RefinementName:descending'
```

The query will sort your response based on your RefinementName in descending order.

Comment: But first I think I should enter the Refiner and then internally order by RefinementName, otherwise the refiner results wold be null.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can

check this example out:

```
https://sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='justatest'&refinementfilters='filetype:equals("pptx")&sortlist='filetype:ascending'
```

EDIT (check updated REST URL too):

Please be sure, that the property, which are as an refinment property is an sortable property, too! Than you can use the ["sortlist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj163876.aspx#bk_SortList)"

Check this out to configure search: [Sorting Not Working in the Search Results Web Part in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138133/sorting-not-working-in-the-search-results-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013/138159#138159)

Comment: I need the result to be sorted or order by.

Comment: see updated awnser